# Decay of linear system with damping

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

Let us consider the following linear system with damping:
$$
\begin{cases}
u_t - u_x = -\frac{1}{2} a(x) (u+v)\\
v_t + v_x = -\frac{1}{2} a(x) (u+v)
\end{cases}
$$
where $a(x) = \mathbf{1}_{(-\infty,-1)\cup(1,\infty)}(x)$.

Let's write the solution as $w=(u,v)$ corresponding to initial data $w_0 := w(0,\cdot) \in L^1(\mathbb R) \cap L^2(\mathbb R)$.

If $a \equiv 1$, we can prove that $$w=w_1+w_2$$
where
$$\|w_1\|_{L^2} \lesssim e^{-\alpha t}\|w_0\|_{L^2}, \qquad \|w_2\|_{L^\infty} \lesssim t^{-1/2}\|w_0\|_{L^1}$$
using Fourier transform.

Can we prove something similar also for the choice of $as$ as $a(x) = \mathbf{1}_{(-\infty,-1)\cup(1,\infty)}(x)$?